# Unable to convert audio file format in php using shell commands

Tags: php, shell, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert the uploaded audio file to .mp3 format using PHP.
ffmpeg is enabled in my server.

I try to execute shell commands, but it does not convert the file format of the audio file. `exec()` and `shell_exec()` are both enabled.

```
<?php 
    $uploadpath = realpath('./') . '/musicfolder/';

    $filedata = $_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    if ($filedata != '' && $filename != ''){


        list($name,$ext) = explode('.',$filename);
        $file_mp3=$name.".mp3";
        $file_wav=$name.".wav";
        shell_exec(' ffmpeg -i '.$filename.' -ac 1 -ab 16000 -ar 8000 '.$file_mp3.'');



        if($can_create){
            copy($filedata,$uploadpath.$filename);
            echo "-file_update_successful-";
        }

    }


?>
```

I don't understand where I made mistake. Can I achieve this using `system()`?

Comment: ffmpeg binary path is correct? Try to log the output of shell_exec to see what is happening.

Comment: yes path is correct @marcellorvalle

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the filenames via [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) like:

```
$file_mp3 = escapeshellcmd($name . ".mp3");
$file_wav = escapeshellcmd($name . ".wav");
```

And you are messing a lot up here.
For security reasons you should first check if the file was uploaded with [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php).

Then you should try to convert *$filedata* instead of *$filename*

I'm not sure what you are trying to build but it's always good practice to validate user input.

With your script it's possible to upload a file to a different location than you would expect.

For example one could post a binary file and post a filename like *'../../bin/admintool.exe'*
This will end up like:

```
copy($filedata, '/musicfolder/../../bin/admintool.exe');
echo "-file_update_successful-";
```